# Why does Integer.tostring throw this nullpointer exception?

Tags: android, arrays, nullpointerexception

My application is throwing a nullpointer exception in Createview when I try to use an int array value retrieved from bundle. It only happens rarely and I haven't been able to recreate it myself.

I have declared and initialized int array variable here:

```
       public class  ScoreViewerFragment extends Fragment {
...
                  private int[] playerScores = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

I tried to fix the null pointer exception by checking for null here:

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        if (arguments != null) {
            playerScores=arguments.getIntArray(PLAYER_SCORES_ARRAY);
        }
```

This is where the nullpointer exception is thrown. integer.tostring(playerscores[3])

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
              String i3= Integer.toString(playerScores[3]);
```

Please help me fix it. If there is anymore information needed please let me know. I really don't understand how it is possible after already checking for null when retrieving the bundle.

Comment: you're checking `if (arguments != null)` but where are you checking that the value you take from these arguments isn't null ? how do you know `playerScores` isn't null ?

Comment: I thought that an int arrays value couldn't be null. Is this incorrect? if so what would be an appropriate way to check this? Thanks

Comment: `I thought that an int arrays value couldn't be null.` the values inside of the array have nothing to do with the actual array being null. you're doing `playerScores[3]` without ever checking `if (playerScores != null)` and also, as a side note, you're also just assuming that you have an index of [3], you never check that it actually exists either